# Storing the output into shell variable

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell, centos

I wish to store the Output of the following command over my postgres database

> **sudo -u postgres -H -- psql -d firstdb -c"select count(col2) from
>   table2;"**

into a variable defined in shell.
I saw this way somewhere-

> **abc=sudo -u postgres -H -- psql -d firstdb -c"select count(col2) from
>   table2;"
>   echo abc**

but seems to be not working 
Is there any other way to store the output so as to apply cut query to fetch the value and check for the size of column??

Comment: You can do `abc=$(command)` in most shells to store output into variables.

Comment: I did use $(command) but that too didn't work!!

Comment: To be clear, you would do: `abc=$(sudo -u postgres -H -- psql -d firstdb -c"select count(col2) from table2;")`, and then `echo $abc` to see the output...   Note, that this will capture stdout, not stderr...

Comment: Is there any way to cut or grep the count(*) value out of stdout from this

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after, but you can use `awk '{print $2}'` to print out a particular column (2nd column in this case) of an output.   You could alternatively use `sed` to strip out any `count=_val_` patterns from the text.   Or if you're actually looking for the number of lines, you can pipe the output into `wc`.   You'll have to `man` those commands to see how to use them properly.

Comment: `abc=$(sudo -u postgres -H -- psql -d firstdb -X -q -c "copy (select count(col2) from table2) to stdout"; echo $abc` should works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
abc=$(svn://solace2/svn/vrs32/branches/feature/ipv6_support 2>&1)
```

and then do `echo $abc` to see the output.   Notice the 2>&1 at the end will redirect stderr to stdout before assigning stdout to the variable, meaning `abc` will contain error messages as well as regular messages.